# missing route for wifi modem in ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, iptables

After disconnecting my openvpn client on a Xenial 16.04 machine, I'm having trouble connecting to the internet and it appears I'm missing a route on my Kernel IP routing table.

On the machine that *is not* working I have:

```
> route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
```

I have a very similar machine running 16.04 that *is* working  and the same command returns:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

I assume that these are set up automatically with the wifi and dhcp configurations

Can someone tell me how to set up the "not working" machine so that it gets all the routes?

The following commands give the following responses (as per request in comments)

```
> cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search Belkin
```

and

```
    >  ping 127.0.1.1
PING 127.0.1.1 (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
^C
--- 127.0.1.1 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 5997ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.035/0.040/0.044/0.006 ms
```

Comment: Can you please also include the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` before hitting the issue?
Also, `ping 10.20.30.41` is trying to reach *my* name-server. You should try to ping the ip addresses in your resolv.conf (in your case 127.0.1.1).

Comment: Hi the output of cat /etc/resolve.conf is above

Comment: Does resolve.conf look exactly like that (`nameserver 127.0.1.1`) even when you are being able to reach internet? I am asking that because 127.0.1.1 almost certainly is one of the loopback addresses of your local machine, whereas I believe your DNS server is usually your router. In that case I would expect to see an entry in resolv.conf like `nameserver A.B.C.D` where A.B.C.D is the IP of your router (this entry is being dynamically added to resolv.conf when your local machine successfully receives a DHCP response)

Comment: Yes its *exactly* like that on both machines, the one where wifi networking works, and the one that doesn't

Comment: Entirely expected in 16.04 :) I've updated my answer to reflect that. Does restarting NetworkManager get rid of the issue?: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: thanks for your ongoing help, i just tried "sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager" and it doesn't resolve the problem.  Do you want me to give you more diagnostic, perhaps there is some issue from vestigial settings from openvp (perhaps in iptables).  Would the printouts of lspci -nnk  grep -iA2 net            iwconfig            rfkill list all         iptables -L     help at all?    also when I show the connection info, it shows the primary DNS as 192.168.10.1 but I can't even ping that ip address it gives me "Destination Host Unreachable"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74778/discussion-between-simon-b-and-lubumbax).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I have removed that route from my machine and still can reach Internet. Hence I am not so sure that this is what prevents you from "connecting to the Internet".

Maybe you are just not being able to resolve names? 
You can check that with `dig`. This is how `dig` resolves `www.google.com` for me:

```
$ dig www.google.com A +short
108.177.126.105
108.177.126.106
108.177.126.99
108.177.126.103
108.177.126.104
108.177.126.147
```

**Edit:**
If that doesn't resolve, check that you have one or more name-servers configured and that you can (IP) reach at least one of them:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
...
nameserver 10.20.30.41
nameserver 10.20.30.42
```

In this example the machines at 10.20.30.41 and 10.20.30.42 are configured to resolve names (ie: *dig* will access those those machines on port 53 by default in order to resolve `www.cisco.com` to an IP address).
Thus, those two machines are expected to be reachable and have a DNS service listening on port 53.

Now try to ping those two machines to see if they are reachable:

```
$ ping 10.20.30.41
...
64 bytes from 10.20.30.41: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.194 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.30.41: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.209 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.30.41: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.235 ms
^C
```

The previous output shows that the machine at 10.20.30.41 is being reachable. If it wasn't you would not see any output (until you `^C`).

**Edit2**:
In Ubuntu 16.04 the file `/etc/resolv.conf` contains a `nameserver 127.0.1.1` entry which means there has to be a DNS server on the local machine.
Indeed Ubuntu 16.04 runs *Dnsmasq* which acts as a small local DNS server. Dnsmasq is handled by *NetworkManager* by default.

Comment: I think you're right, I've added that route with an "ip route add 169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp4s0" but it still doesn't connect.  ping returns me destination unreachable.  The dig command that you put returns "connection timed out; no servers could be reached", any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems you can't reach your name-server. I have edited my answer with further steps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've included the outputs of the commands you requested from me in the original post at the bottom

Comment: Added the updated output for the ping 127.0.0.1